# Hibernate - 3-way Many to Many using Embeddable

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a 3-way Many to Many relationship between User, Group Role and Group. In some instances I would like to be able to define roles for a User based on groups they are in, and display/edit/create these etc. To do so, I created a GroupUserRoles table with an embedded ID, using user, group role and group ID's as a composite key, and mapped user, group and group role as many to many in this entity and then mapped GroupUserRoles as One to Many in these entities. However, when trying to a Users Group Roles through user.groupUserRoles.group, I get the following error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'groupuserr0_.user_userID' in 'field list'`

Hibernate produces the associated query: `Hibernate: select groupuserr0_.user_userID as user_use3_6_0_, groupuserr0_.group_groupID as group_gr1_6_0_, groupuserr0_.groupRole_groupRoleID as grouprol2_6_0_, groupuserr0_.group_groupID as group_gr1_6_1_, groupuserr0_.groupRole_groupRoleID as grouprol2_6_1_, groupuserr0_.user_userID as user_use3_6_1_ from GroupUserRoles groupuserr0_ where groupuserr0_.user_userID=?`

Entities (getters and setters etc omitted):
Composite Key Entity

```
@Embeddable
public class GroupUserRolesID implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "groupID")
    private Long groupID;

    @Column(name = "groupRoleID")
    private Long groupRoleID;
    
    @Column(name = "userID")
    private Long userID;
    
    private GroupUserRolesID() {}

    public GroupUserRolesID(Long groupRoleID, Long groupID, Long userID) {
        this.groupRoleID = groupRoleID;
        this.groupID = groupID;
        this.userID = userID;
    }

@Entity(name = "GroupUserRoles")
public class GroupUserRoles {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupUserRolesID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("groupRoleID")
    private GroupRole groupRole;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("groupID")
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userID")
    private User user;

    public GroupUserRoles(GroupRole groupRole, Group group, User user) {
        this.groupRole = groupRole;
        this.group = group;
        this.user = user;
        this.id = new GroupUserRolesID(groupRole.getId(), group.getGroupID(), user.getUserId());
    }
```

User Entity

```
 @Entity
    public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name = "userHashedPassword")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<GroupUserRoles> groupUserRoles = new HashSet<>();
```

Group and Group Role follow the same pattern as User. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Obviously MySQL tells you that the table `GroupUserRoles` has no column named `user_userID`. Since you are using `@Column(name = "userID")`, the only way why the column name could change is if you use a hibernate naming strategy. Ensure that this is all correct and that the column really exists.